# SQL сервер сохраняет удаленные данные

Tags: python, sql, ubuntu, sql-server

Я сохраняю картинки в формате BLOB в SQL таблицу на сервере ubuntu, а после того, как я их удаляю через DELETE FROM pictures WHERE id = ? они удаляются с таблицы, но почему то память все равно занимается, и мне приходится сбрасывать весь сервер, чтобы ее отчистить. Как
это пофиксить? Нужно сделать так, чтобы когда я удалял строку из таблицы память отчищалась.

Comment: Commit? Shrink?

Comment: [Shrink a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-database?view=sql-server-ver16). [Shrink a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-file?view=sql-server-ver16). Но вообще это не рекомендуется делать.

Comment: Кстати, о какой памяти речь? Может, об оперативной? Тогда см. [Server memory configuration options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Не надо картинки держать в базе денных. Держите их в файлах, файловые системы гораздо лучше приспособлены для хранения таких данных и к своевременному освобождению места

Comment: https://imgur.com/kA0NuT9
Вот об этой памяти идет речь